# AES Encryption in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, encryption

The [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography#kotlin) give the following snippet for how to encrypt a message in AES:

```
val plaintext: ByteArray = ...
val keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
keygen.init(256)
val key: SecretKey = keygen.generateKey()
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
val ciphertext: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(plaintext)
val iv: ByteArray = cipher.iv
```

I get this error when implementing this method:

> Unresolved reference: Cipher

So it appears the 'Cipher' object isn't native, however I have no way of knowing how to import it by following the Android docs. **How do I set up my project to be able to use 'Cipher'?**

Comment: [`javax.crypto.Cipher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/javax/crypto/Cipher) is part of the JCE and should be available. Does an `import javax.crypto.Cipher` not work? Then maybe something is wrong with your environment.

Comment: Interesting. That looks like it will work, however I'm not sure how I was supposed to know about it according to docs. Also, I don't even know how the above code works. Why is "plaintext" declared as a ByteArray? Where is the password? Why is the declaration of the iv in the last step? Where does the final encryption happen?

Comment: I'm going to edit the question as I have no idea how to encrypt a string with the above code "snippet"

Comment: @metamonkey please check my updated answer once :)

Comment: The questions from the comment can all be answered from the documentation (e.g.:  _Why is "plaintext" declared as a `ByteArray`?_ Since `doFinal()` expects a `ByteArray`) or can be answered with basic cryptographic knowledge (e.g.: _Why is the declaration of the iv in the last step?_ Because it is needed for decryption). Regarding the _Edit_ in your question: If you want to use a password instead of a key, you should use a password-based key derivation function like PBKDF2 or Argon2.

Comment: I don't want to use a password instead of a key. I just want to generate a key based on a password, not randomly. Also, I understand that doFinal() expects a ByteArray, but who is encrypting a ByteArray? Is it assumed that I will know to convert my String to a bytearray prior to the operation?

Comment: Also regarding: (e.g.: Why is the declaration of the iv in the last step? Because it is needed for decryption). What does this mean? Do I need to pass my iv to my Decrypter? Doesn't this violate the purpose of an iv?

Comment: As the name suggests, a password-based key derivation function derives a key from a password. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: For encryption, a non-secret IV is used. This is automatically generated by the code during encryption (the IV must be random). During decryption  the _same_ IV  is needed. The code shows how you can get this IV.

Comment: What I want is to understand these docs because I need to mimic the encryption employed in a custom dart script to this script. Specifically I want to be able to use an AES/SIC/PKCS7Padding implementation with nothing but a password (Or key) and a string to be encrypted/decrypted. I have employed this successfully from dart to JS, but cannot seem to do this on Kotlin.

Comment: The IV comment is interesting, because I encrypt/decrypt the strings given the above AES/SIC/PKCS7Padding in/across dart and js on any device without ever saving or passing an IV

Comment: I don't think your question in its current form is appropriate for SO. It is too imprecise and general. It lacks focus. If you have a working Dart (or JavaScript) implementation, you should post it. Also, you should post a first draft of a Kotlin implementation. Then one would have a starting point to work with.

Comment: Alright I'll delete this question

Comment: Actually, I'll remit my edit. The initial question was simple and could be useful.

Comment: Alternatively, you could edit your question and post the information needed to answer it. But of course that is up to you.

Comment: @user9014097 if you post an answer with your initial comment ("javax.crypto.Cipher is part of the JCE and should be available. Does an import javax.crypto.Cipher not work? Then maybe something is wrong with your environment. ) I will accept.

Comment: Sure. I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`javax.crypto.Cipher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) is part of the JCE and should be available. Does an import `javax.crypto.Cipher` not work? Then maybe something is wrong with your environment.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if using that `Cipher` is necessary, and if the solution I'm providing is the best approach, but I was able to use `AES` for `encryption` and `decryption` using the following code for a `text` input, means a `String`:

**ENCRYPTION**

```
// text

val aesEncrypt: AESEncrypt = AESEncrypt()
val encryptedByteArray = aesEncrypt.encrypt(text)
val baos_text = ByteArrayOutputStream()
val oosText = ObjectOutputStream(baos_text)
oosText.writeObject(encryptedByteArray)
val encryptedText = String(android.util.Base64.encode(baos_text.toByteArray(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT))

// key

val key = aesEncrypt.mySecretKey
val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
val oos = ObjectOutputStream(baos)
oos.writeObject(key)
val keyAsString = String(android.util.Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT))

// initialisation vector

val iv = aesEncrypt.myInitializationVector
val baosIV = ByteArrayOutputStream()
val oosIV = ObjectOutputStream(baosIV)
oosIV.writeObject(iv)
val initialisationVector = String(android.util.Base64.encode(baosIV.toByteArray(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT))
```

**DECRYPTION**

You must save the `key`, `initialisation vector`, and the `encrypted text` in order to decrypt it back.

```
val initialisationVector = ... // get from wherever you saved it, local db, firebase...

val bytesIV = android.util.Base64.decode(iv, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)
val oisIV = ObjectInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(bytesIV))
val initializationVectorIV = oisIV.readObject() as ByteArray


val encryptedText = ... // get 

val bytesText = android.util.Base64.decode(encryptedText, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)
val oisText = ObjectInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(bytesText))
val textByteArray = oisText.readObject() as ByteArray


val key = ... // get your key
val bytesKey = android.util.Base64.decode(key, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)
val oisKey = ObjectInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(bytesKey))
val secretKeyObj = oisKey.readObject() as SecretKey


val aesDecrypt = AESDecrypt(secretKeyObj,initializationVectorIV)
val decryptedByteArray = aesDecrypt.decrypt(textByteArray)

val textAfterDecryption = decryptedByteArray.toString(charset("UTF-8"))
```

**EDIT**

AES helper class:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
import javax.crypto.SecretKey

class AESEncrypt {

    var mySecretKey: SecretKey? = null
    var myInitializationVector: ByteArray? = null

    fun encrypt(strToEncrypt: String): ByteArray {

        val plainText = strToEncrypt.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
        val keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
        keygen.init(256)

        val key = keygen.generateKey()
        mySecretKey = key

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
        val cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText)
        myInitializationVector = cipher.iv

        return cipherText
    }

}
```

AES decrypt helper

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec

class AESDecrypt(private val mySecretKey: SecretKey?, private val initializationVector: ByteArray?) {

    fun decrypt(dataToDecrypt: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
        val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(initializationVector)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mySecretKey, ivSpec)
        val cipherText = cipher.doFinal(dataToDecrypt)

        return cipherText
    }

}
```

Do tell if you still need any help :)

Comment: What kind of AES is this? i.e. Block cipher? What padding? Etc. Also, Save the initialization vector? That doesn't make sense imo.

Comment: Ok my bad, it was an old code and I forgot that this helper class was indeed created by me and yes it does use `Cipher`. Let me update my answer

Comment: Can you edit the answer to show a password input instead of just generating a new key?

Comment: Also, I am having trouble understanding how the iv is used here in the encrypt method?

Comment: I mean, the `text` that I used when `encrypting`, you could replace with any `String` you like and most probably the password is going to be a `String` as well, though passwords aren't encrypted, rather they are `hashed` for storing so they can't be `decrypted` back.

Comment: Regarding the `iv`, the variable `myInitializationVector` is present inside the class `AESEncrypt` and is getting value when encrypting an object, yes it does need to be saved  and not just be in memory like that, but this was a sample app so I had implemented it this way. Then this `myInitializationVector` is used as `iv` for encryption as well.

Comment: Forgive me, but my understanding is that an iv should not need to be saved and passed along. This defeats the purpose of an iv. An iv should at best be random, no?

Comment: I'm not really sure on this either, but in that case, you could have the `iv` be something that you already know so you don't need it to be passed and rely on it, I haven't used it so much but just a very basic version, let me know if you find out anything about it :)

Comment: In your line: val encryptedText = String(android.util.Base64.encode(baos_text.toByteArray(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)), did u intend for that to be oosText instead of baos_text?

Comment: nope `oos` is only used for writing it is an `object output stream`

Comment: also, what you can do is, somehow find a way to keep the same key at both sender and receiver. It is not just the `iv` that must be hidden but the `key` as well since both are used while decryption.

Comment: An IV "just" needs to be *fully unpredictable* to an attacker for CBC mode, often is is just 16 random bytes prefixed directly to the ciphertext.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes so the same `iv` must be known to the receiver, right? How does the receiver get it then if it is unpredictable also needs to be sent along with the message every time? In my case, I was just saving all 3 values, the `iv`, the `key` and the `message` in firebase db and then decrypting back at the receiver side. I wasn't sure where to store the `iv` or `key` so for that time I decided to send it along, it was a test project :)

Comment: It needs to be unpredictable to the attacker at the moment it is used for encryption. Storing the iv and message in separate locations of the same DB is fine. But for the key: *key management* is the subject of entire books; storing the key next to the ciphertext obviously is not a good idea; the key should be less accessible than the ciphertext almost by definition (otherwise: what are you protecting against?).

Comment: Also, using PKCS5 padding with AES is a mistake, you should use PKCS7. PKCS5 is not meant to be used with AES